# Solana Bigquery public dataset is not up-to-date

Tags: solana-program

As of 2024/03/19, the most updated block in BigQuery Solana dataset is at 2024/03/17 which is not up-to-date.

I understand that this can happen because the datasets are maintained by the Solana community but I wonder if there is a place to monitor its availability.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You're probably better off submitting an issue at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues to get some feedback